# Group query doesn't value corresponding values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which works alright in grouping from the highest order. What i've realized is its able to pick up the `ids` alright but the values of the `vmsg` field is not corresponding to that of the `id`.

For example id of `28` corresponds with a `vsmg` 'hello' but after you run the query id of `28` picks a different value .

This is how it looks from the backend

[image]

and with my script

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id) as id, vmsg, sender_id, fname, lname, profile_pix, profile.profile_id
FROM 
    chats 
LEFT JOIN 
    profile 
ON 
    chats.sender_id = profile.profile_id
WHERE 
    reciever_id = 1
GROUP BY 
    (sender_id)
```

I get this :

[image]

I get the max `ids` but the `vmsg` values don't correspond.

Comment: Dear when you apply group by and aggregate function, if you use scalar field not present in group by MySql take the first.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), or return unpredictable results with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Rather than `MAX()` try to use `ORDER BY` on id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the data corresponding to the `MAX(id)`, you can modify your query something like :

```
SELECT 
   c.id, c.vmsg, c.sender_id, c.fname, c.lname, p.profile_pix, p.profile_id
FROM 
    chats c 
LEFT JOIN 
    profile p 
ON
    c.sender_id = p.profile_id
WHERE 
    c.reciever_id = 1
AND 
    c.id 
        IN (
            SELECT 
                MAX(c.id) as id
            FROM 
                chats c 
            GROUP BY 
                c.sender_id 
        )
```

This will fetch only the data that is corresponding to the `MAX(id)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer i want add count to my query but it seems when i count it only bring out one result. can you check it for me: SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN page='n' and reciever_id=1  THEN 'loved' ELSE 'not loved' END) AS love_answer, c.id, c.vmsg, c.sender_id, p.fname, p.lname, p.profile_pix, p.profile_id
FROM chats c LEFT JOIN profile p  ON c.sender_id = p.profile_id
WHERE c.reciever_id = 1 AND c.id in (SELECT MAX(c.id) as id FROM  chats c
GROUP BY c.sender_id)

Answer (score 0):

**My strategy:** You'll get all raws about chat where the id for the same `id_sender_id` and `reciever_id` is the maximum (so doesn't exist the next row for this couple)

Try this:

```
SELECT id,vmsg,sender_id,fname,lname,profile_pix,profile.profile_id
FROM chats c LEFT JOIN profile p
on chats.sender_id = profile.profile_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 'NEXT' FROM chat c2
    WHERE c2.id_sender_id = c.id_sender_id
    AND c2.reciever_id = c.reciever_id 
    AND c2.id > c.id)
AND reciever_id = 1
```